# Visual Studio auto version commenting on save

Tags: comments, visual-studio-addins

Is there a Visual Studio add-in which adds a line of comment at the top of the source file on save with someting like below?

/* Modified @ 2011-08-18 12:00 by John Smith - #some text */

Asking for "some text" or confirmation would be nice.

ty!

Comment: Usually this information goes into the commit log of the Versioning System nowadays.

Comment: I know, but I need the above now.

Comment: What version control system do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this feature is available in JustCode for Telerik. You can check http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx. However this is a paid product and if someone knows of something similar that is free, please let me know.